# How to pass functions parameters in a register with gcc asm keyword

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, parameter-passing, calling-convention

In gcc you can declare that a local variable should be put in a register using the following syntax.

```
register int arg asm("eax");
```

In some old code I found on the internet this syntax was used to declare that the parameters to a function should be passed in a register:

```
void foo(register int arg asm("eax"))
```

But when I try this example:

```
/*
   Program to demonstrate usage of asm keyword to allocate register for a variable.
*/
#include <stdio.h>

/* Function with argument passed in register */
void foo(register int arg asm("eax") )
{
    register int loc asm("ebx");
    loc = arg;
    printf("foo() local var: %d\n", loc);
}

int main(void)
{
    foo(42);
    return 0;
}
```

And compile with gcc I get an error:

```
gcc main.c -o test-asm.exe
main.c:7:27: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'asm'
```

Now my questions are:
Is the asm syntax above correct, in gcc that is, for formal parameters of a function?
Has this ever been supported by gcc?
If this is not the correct syntax, how can this be accomplished then?

Thanks,
//jk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only method I know of is using the fastcall attribute:

(GCC Manual section 6.30) http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes

> fastcall
>
> On the Intel 386, the fastcall attribute causes the compiler to pass the first argument (if of integral type) in the register ECX and
>   the second argument (if of integral type) in the register EDX.
>   Subsequent and other typed arguments are passed on the stack. The
>   called function will pop the arguments off the stack. If the number of
>   arguments is variable all arguments are pushed on the stack.

Using it in on the following example code:

```
__attribute__((fastcall,noinline)) int add (int a, int b)
{
  return a + b;
}

int main () {
  return add (1, 2);
}
```

will result in:

```
    .file   "main.c"
    .text
.globl add
    .type   add, @function
add:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    leal    (%edx,%ecx), %eax
    popl    %ebp
    ret
    .size   add, .-add
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    movl    $2, %edx
    movl    $1, %ecx
    call    add
    popl    %ebp
    ret
    .size   main, .-main
```

Don't forget to mention the fastcall attribute in any declaration in other translation units, otherwise rather strange things might happen.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I thought there may be, or have been, a more general syntax supported by gcc.

Comment: Wow, how ugly that more than half of the generated function is useless prologue/epilogue crap... Is that with `-O0` or...?

Comment: Nope - with -O0 it gets even funnier as parameters passed via ecx and edx for whatever reason will get stored on the stack first. This is (without joke) what gcc will do with -O0 : `add:
 pushl %ebp
 movl %esp, %ebp
 subl $8, %esp
 movl %ecx, -4(%ebp)
 movl %edx, -8(%ebp)
 movl -8(%ebp), %eax
 movl -4(%ebp), %edx
 leal (%edx,%eax), %eax
 leave
 ret`

Comment: There's also `gcc -mregparm=3`, or as a per-function attribute.